# Azure pipelines using a (react) node.js and express project using concurrently script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have finished a full stack website

This is created using react,express and with a sql server database.

1.I have set up a agent pool for this.

2.I then set up a visual studio database model of my sql database and saved this into a repo

3.I then set up the pipeline for this database.

I am now setting up a node.js pipeline for my react app.This project uses a script within the package.json using concurrently (npm package) to run both my front end and express server file together.

This script is called "npm run dev"

Will I need to include this into my pipeline or will when this is built give it the same functionality.

I am new to setting up piplines does everything mentioned above seem in order? Do i need to add this script? Is there anything I have missed?

This is what my pipeline consists of already

```
# Node.js
# Build a general Node.js project with npm.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Will I need to include this into my pipeline or will when this is
>   built give it the same functionality.
>
> Do i need to add this script? Is there anything I have missed?

Check [this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops#react-and-vue): *All the dependencies for your React and Vue apps are captured in your package.json file.*

The above script is enough for you. If you just need to run `npm run dev` to start your front end and express server file together, I think you should replace the `npm run build` with `npm run dev` in above script.

(It calls the dev script defined in `scripts`)

`npm run dev` will call the `dev` script defined in `package.json` and `npm run build` will call the `build` script. Normally we use `npm run dev` to start application during **Dev** environment and use `build` script when we need to pack and deploy it to **Prod** environment.

So it depends on your need to use whether `npm run build` or `npm run dev` in above script.